# How YARN and Spark makes decision to choose a work node?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

As my understanding, when Yarn create jobs, it will chooses the one which stores the data pending on processing as the work node, because moving data is expensive than moving code, local processing will significantly reduce network traffic cost. But my question is, Yarn job is based on container technology, how if the node with the data doesn't have enough resource to announce the container? What will happens to Yarn?

An other question is how Spark does the same thing? as it is based on RDD's partition, which is logic division of the data, and usually Spark's Worker node is not running over the same machine of datanode, doesn't like NodeManager for Yarn shares same machine with HDFS, how it handles the data transfer cost? and how it decides where to run the jobs?